# Replace X with Y and Y with X in a single Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Say I have the following:

```
var strRandomString = "I have 2 apples and 6 oranges and 3 grapes";
```

Now I want to replace the word "apples" with the word "oranges" and vice-versa.  Order is not fixed and replace should be global.  This makes the end result:

```
document.write(strRandomString) \\"I have 2 oranges and 6 apples and 3 grapes";
```

Currently, the best way I can think to do this is:

```
strRandomString=strRandomString.replace("apples","*******");
strRandomString=strRandomString.replace("oranges","apples");
strRandomString=strRandomString.replace("*******","oranges");
```

Is there a way to do this with a single replace?

Comment: well what effort have you made?

Comment: How did you replace the one?

Comment: Searching has provided no results, but I may be missing the proper keywords to find anything.

Comment: @DanielA.White I mentioned how it could be accomplished, but I've added the specific code to better demonstrate.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Order is not fixed, updated question to be a bit clearer.

Comment: Replacing(swap) algorithm is not possible without a placeholder. to swap 2 elements, at least 1 placeholder is a need and a must. However for this example. String it self can be used as a placeholder.(And that is what you did in your edit). Do you need some sort of standalone function? You kinda answered your question with the most basic solution.

Comment: A pure regex solution is not possible, but you can use a callback function to decide which replacement text to use. Would that be acceptable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`String.prototype.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) not only accepts string as a replacement, but also accepts a function. The return value of the function is used as replacement string.

```
var strRandomString = "I have 2 apples and 6 oranges and 3 grapes";
strRandomString.replace(/apples|oranges/g, function(m) {
    // `m` is a matched string.
    return m === 'apples' ? 'oranges' : 'apples';
})
// => "I have 2 oranges and 6 apples and 3 grapes"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something with capture groups

```
var strRandomString = "I have 2 apples and 6 oranges and 3 grapes";
console.log(strRandomString.replace(/(apples|oranges)(.+)(apples|oranges)/g,"$3$2$1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you could always makes things a bit more elegant by adding a function on the string's prototype:

```
String.prototype.switch = function(str1, str2){
   var delimiter = '__#$@%__';
   return this.replace(str1, delimiter).replace(str2,str1).replace(delimiter,str2);
}

var str = "orange apple switch";
var newStr = str.switch("orange","apple");
console.log(newStr);
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wqngve3y/)**