# Improve chained regex to replace vowels

Tags: javascript, regex

I was presented with a **JavaScript** code challenge to create a function that will substitute all instances of a, e, i, o, u in a string with 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 (respectively).
For example, "How about this string?" should become "H3w 0b34t th2s str2ng?"

Here's how I solved the problem:

```js
const hackerSpeak = (str) => {
return str.replace(/[aA]/g, 0).replace(/[eE]/g, 1).replace(/[iI]/g, 2).replace(/[oO]/g, 3).replace(/[uU]/g, 4)
}
```

I'm fairly new to RegEx, and find myself wondering if there's a simpler way that would avoid chaining. Could I combine the RegEx into one expression that would know to replace aeiou with 01234 respectively?

An answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25367347/replace-x-with-y-and-y-with-x-in-a-single-regular-expression) led me to look into capture groups and back referencing, but it seems that's for re-ordering/swapping the aeiou characters rather than replacing them with 01234. (Though I'm happy to be corrected.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be able to vary the mapping from e.g. `a -> 0` to something else then you can use this approach:

```js
const str = "the cat sat on the mat and the cow in the undergrowth";
const mapping1 = { a: 0, e: 1, i: 2, o: 3, u: 4 }
const mapping2 = { a: "!", e: "foo", i: "bar", o: "fizz", u: "buzz" }
const hackerSpeak = (str, mapping) => {
  return str.replace(/(a)|(e)|(i)|(o)|(u)/gi, k => mapping[k]);
}
console.log(str);
console.log(hackerSpeak(str, mapping1));
console.log(hackerSpeak(str, mapping2));
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `replace` with a callback.

```
const hackerSpeak = (str) => {
    return str.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, x => 'aeiou'.indexOf(x.toLowerCase()));
}
```

Comment from [Pointy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy):

> To add some detail, the callback function is passed each match. The
> callback function returns what `.replace()` should use to replaced the
> matching part of the string. Here, the `gi` suffix on the regex makes it
> a "global" match, so `.replace()` will keep trying until the end of the
> source string, and `i` makes it ignore case (so upper and lower case
> both match).

Comment: To add some detail, the callback function is passed each match. The callback function returns what `.replace()` should use to replaced the matching part of the string. Here, the `gi` suffix on the regex makes it a "global" match, so `.replace()` will keep trying until the end of the source string, and `i` makes it ignore case (so upper and lower case both match).